# how does the history command send only unix commands to the history file in a shell programmed in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have an assignment that requires me to create a history command, and I am stuck trying to figure out how the program would recognize that the input is a Unix command then send it to a file. If a user types junk, then it would not be sent to the history file; but if they type something like `date`, that would be sent to the history file.

Comment: Bash doesn't care if it's "junk", it's going in the history file.

Comment: Have a look at bash's `type` builtin.

Comment: Seems like you might want to check the details of the assignment, as the behavior you seem to be looking for seems atypical.

Comment: If the shell history doesn't record variable assignments, internal constructs (`for` loops, etc), then it isn't going to be very useful.  Note, too, that although it is aconventional to do so, you can put I/O redirections in front of commands: `> output 2> errors command args`.  This should still be recorded in history.  Basically, about the only thing you might decide not to record would be comments where the line starts with the comment.  OTOH, it is easier just to record everything.

Comment: I should have gone this path but the instructions are sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "look" into the environment variable PATH, and if the first word of the command correspond to a program that's inside the PATH, or (if it begin with a "/" and the program exist), you write that to the file. Good luck!

Comment: Is this the actual behavior you see?  If so on which shell?  When I type garbage into bash as jordanm suggested above, it does show in history.

Comment: I had understood that's a school assignement, so maybe it doesn't have to behave exactly like a real shell history, so the wrong command don't go in the history, but I may have read wrong

Comment: I'll definitely look into this. At this point i've found a different "solution", since my simple shell doesn't use many unix commands, I just made an if statement for 4 different commands. looks ugly but technically does the job. Just as an aside, does anyone know why my while loop is returning 11? if I put return 0, the simple shell dies.